# C# - calling jquery through view not actually firing method

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I'm attempting to do jquery through a view and it is not firing off the back end method i'm not sure why it's not calling correctly and need a second (or third) set of eyes on the issue.

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type ="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("[data-form]").each
        (
            function (formDiv)
            {
                $(formDiv).children("input[type='button']").each
                (
                    function (elem)
                    {
                        elem.click
                        (
                            function () {

                                var formName = $(formDiv).attr("data-form").val();

                                var qString = "";

                                $(formDiv).children("input[type!='button']").each
                                (
                                    function (inp) {
                                        var name = $(inp).attr("name").val();
                                        var val = $(inp).val();
                                        qString += name + "=" + val + "&";
                                    }
                                );

                                qString = qString.substring(0, qString.length - 1);

                                switch (formName) {
                                    case 'DQPOST':
                                        $.ajax("/api/D/DQPost?" + qString,
                                       function (resp) {
                                           alert(resp);
                                       });
                                        break;
                                    case 'DQReply':
                                        $.ajax("/api/D/DQReply?" + qString,
                                       function (resp) {
                                           alert(resp);
                                       });
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    });

 </script>

<h2>D-Profiles</h2>

@foreach(var up in Model)
{
    @up._id

    <div data-form="DQPost">
        <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="@up._id" />
        <h7>The thread ID</h7>
        <input type="text" name="ThreadID" /><br />
        <h7>The message&nbsp;</h7>
        <input type="text" name="Message" /><br />
        <input type="button" value="Post Comment"/>
    </div>

    <div data-form="DQReply">
        <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="@up._id" />
        <h7>The thread ID</h7>
        <input type="text" name="ThreadID" /><br />
        <h7>The Parent thread ID</h7>
        <input type="text" name="ParentID" /><br />
        <h7>The message&nbsp;</h7>
        <input type="text" name="Message" /><br />
        <input type="button" value="post comment" /><br />
    </div>
}
```

As you can see there is the ability to have multiple profiles logged into the system and that's probably my biggest issue. I don't think I'm handling it correctly.

Any help/insight is appreciated.

Comment: Just call the $.ajax with no other logic. Does this work?

Comment: Have you stepped through it with the debugger? I would assume `formName` isn't getting either of those two values, and case sensitivity may be a factor. Does it enter the `switch`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's this line:

```
var formName = $(formDiv).attr("data-form").val();
```

`$(formDiv).attr("data-form")` is returning a string, which doesn't have a `.val()` method, so the JS is erroring out entirely. Remove the `.val()` part and you should be fine.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/M9ZgP/1/

**Edit:** Ditto for this line:

```
var name = $(inp).attr("name").val();
```

Comment: that helped i was actually looking for that exact problem when you posted it, i found a few other issues.. once i get everything working i'll show what i fixed (incase someone else ever has this issue.)

Comment: @user2448701 - Glad you solved your problem. If this solved the specific question you posted, you can mark it as the answer by clicking the green checkmark.